# Система мониторинга.(zabbix) Построить график по своим данным

Tags: python, мониторинг

Может кто-то сталкивался. Установила zabbix, можно наверно и что- то другое. Есть б/д sql с данными : название запроса(reqvest), время отклика от сервера(time_requ) и текущее время(Time). Могу ли я построить в zabbix график по этим данным. Или может можно где-то в другой системе мониторинга это сделать? Спасибо

Comment: Если не хотите писать что-то совершенно свое, попробуйте https://grafana.com/ - она для таких целей более заточена, чем заббикс.

Comment: Поняла.Спасибо!